# Infrastructure for incident analysis

Tags: incident-analysis

I have a security-critical online service. (API playground available [here](https://duo.money/hackers).) In case of a security incident I want proper infrastructure to analyse what went wrong.

Should I make rolling captures of network traffic (e.g. using `tcpdump`) to allow for replays? What are common practices to prepare post morten incident analysis?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have to use a SIEM (Security Information and Event Management) software. This kind of software is great for analysing security incidents (but they require plenty of your time).

There are commercial and noncommercial SIEMs. HP Arcsight and Splunk (http://www.splunk.com/en_us/solutions/solution-areas/security-and-fraud.html) are really great.

Comment: What you get with a SIEM is log-correlation.  This allows the SIEM to concatenate your logs to identify various behaviors on your network and label them with the type of attack or concern they might be to you.  AlienVault is another good product that starts at a much lower price than Splunk and some of the other products. AV is better suited for SMB I find.